# how to download dropbox files using wget command?

Tags: linux, command-line, dropbox, wget, cloud-storage

Seems I can only download dropbox files using explorer such as chrome and firefox. If I use wget to download, then I would get a file which is in html format. Why?

For example you can open this link

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/mx9eqve5l2ipgyk/test.txt> with explorer, but if you use

  ```
  wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/mx9eqve5l2ipgyk/test.txt
  ```

You would not get the content of this file, why?  The following is part of test.txt to download it, this is not the content of test.txt at all.

So is it possible to download Dropbox files using `wget` rather than explorer?

```
document.observe('script:loaded', function() {
SharingModel.init('test\x2etxt', Util.from_json('\x7b\x22item\x5fid\x22\x3a\x20\x22\x22\x2c\x20\x22secure\x5fhash\x22\x3a\x20\x22\x22\x2c\x20\x22subpath\x22\x3a\x20\x22\x22\x2c\x20\x22tkey\x22\x3a\x20\x22mx9eqve5l2ipgyk\x22\x7d'))
SharingModel.init_file()
$('emsnippet-9911dfc627e1d541').innerHTML = 'test\x2etxt'.em_snippet(50, 0.750).escapeHTML();
$('emsnippet-add7879f5d805012').innerHTML = 'test\x2etxt'.em_snippet(20, 0.750).escapeHTML();
$('emsnippet-981ac0639529f983').innerHTML = 'test\x2etxt'.em_snippet(20, 0.750).escapeHTML();
FilePreview.init_text('https\x3a\x2f\x2fdl\x2edropbox\x2ecom\x2fs\x2fmx9eqve5l2ipgyk\x2ftest\x2etxt', 0)                        });
                    } else if (window.jQuery) {
jQuery(function () {
SharingModel.init('test\x2etxt', Util.from_json('\x7b\x22item\x5fid\x22\x3a\x20\x22\x22\x2c\x20\x22secure\x5fhash\x22\x3a\x20\x22\x22\x2c\x20\x22subpath\x22\x3a\x20\x22\x22\x2c\x20\x22tkey\x22\x3a\x20\x22mx9eqve5l2ipgyk\x22\x7d'))
SharingModel.init_file()
$('emsnippet-9911dfc627e1d541').innerHTML = 'test\x2etxt'.em_snippet(50, 0.750).escapeHTML();
$('emsnippet-add7879f5d805012').innerHTML = 'test\x2etxt'.em_snippet(20, 0.750).escapeHTML();
$('emsnippet-981ac0639529f983').innerHTML = 'test\x2etxt'.em_snippet(20, 0.750).escapeHTML();
FilePreview.init_text('https\x3a\x2f\x2fdl\x2edropbox\x2ecom\x2fs\x2fmx9eqve5l2ipgyk\x2ftest\x2etxt', 0)                        });
                    }
```

I cannot get test.txt with command

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/mx9eqve5l2ipgyk/test.tx


ls -l 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mirror mirror  30K Sep  6 15:01 test.txt
```

Comment: Stupid question: were you logged into DropBox when you tried to download using a browser?

Comment: Using `wget` on your link retrieves `test.txt` (containing the 4 bytes "test") just fine on my side. Maybe something in your `.wgetrc` is causing this?

Comment: @jjlin what is your command? mine is add above

Comment: I used `wget --no-check-cert https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mx9eqve5l2ipgyk/test.txt`. That worked fine for me, but if you want to force a download, you might consider trying `wget --no-check-cert 'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mx9eqve5l2ipgyk/test.txt?dl=1'` instead (note the `?dl=1` query parameter).

Comment: @jjlin so maybe a script is needed if i want to download file from dropbox:)

Comment: Why WGET? Use CURL = `curl https://www.dropbox.com/sh/AAbbCCeeFF123?dl=1 -O -J -L` will preserve the folder/filenames + follows redirects.

Comment: Use `youtube-dl`  – even if you forget to put `?dl=1` at the end (or the link has `dl=0`), it does the right thing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The link in your question is not the link to the file, is a link to the Dropbox page of this file.

If you want to use `wget` to download it, you should copy the link to direct download from the menu that drops when pushing the download button to the right.

In my case, that worked fine.

However, sometimes problems in downloading links from outside the browser relate to parameters other than the link itself. A common element that does not exist when you simply copy the link are the site cookies.

Try this [cool FF add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/) to get the correct `wget` links

And also, especially if we are talking about a known workstation and not a casual one, you can of course install the Dropbox client. This will be the easiest way, just let your box be part of your file structure and eliminate the need of complicated downloads.

See this [askubuntu.com post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126198/how-to-install-dropbox), and the [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) download page.

Comment: Trying to get the direct link in the browser pops up an ad for an upgrade option.  I see the other answer (http://superuser.com/a/486351/106977) involving `?dl=1`, but that does not allow one to get at the link either (probably due to Box's preventing use unless you upgrade).

Comment: @amotzg is there a way to resume the download from dropbox with flag `--continue`? It seems not working to me. (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174850/wget-resume-download-from-dropbox-gives-cant-write-error)

Comment: @PrayagUpd, found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084677/determine-if-server-supports-resume-get-request.

Comment: This add-on helped with a shared dropbox link which requires a password to download it. Note, right clicking on the "download" button, selecting cliget gives you the URL to the ?dl=0 output, which is a smaller file. Changing that to ?dl=1 gives the correct download path.

Comment: Thanks for that extension. Helpful. Wondering why most pages don't give wget links. How are we supposed to figure it out ourselves?

Comment: @5A7335H Note that taking login/state data like session cookies out of browser context is a possible security risk. Also, using the data out of web application context might confuse the server. We aren't supposed to figure it out...

Answer (score 155):

Just add `?dl=1` at the end of the link! For example: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/mx9eqve5l2ipgyk/test.txt?dl=1`

That should give you a fine retrieval of the file in question without adding anything to the file.

One more thing! If you wanna save the file somewhere else use the `-O` option like this

```
wget -O /root/Desktop/test.txt "https://www.dropbox.com/s/mx9eqve5l2ipgyk/test.txt?dl=1"
```

And if you want to have a little bit of GUI you can use `zenity` to mark the location to where the file is going to be downloaded!

Here's an example code:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(zenity --file-selection --directory)
wget -O $dir/test.txt "https://www.dropbox.com/s/mx9eqve5l2ipgyk/test.txt?dl=1"
```

Comment: That is awesome, works out of the box...

Comment: Just used your suggestion to get a shared folder, and received an amazing zip file (miss named). Awesome! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Much better answer than the accepted one. This helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: Is this method still working? Using the command `wget 'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/my_folder_url?dl=1'` I keep getting `ERROR 400: Bad Request`.

Comment: Now I get `500 Internal Server Error`, Dropbox is a real crap.

Comment: It works for me. Even today. This solution is better than the answer

Comment: 2020-07-21 20:36:22 ERROR 400: Bad Request.

Comment: Worked like a charm! But for some reason the file name is not equal to what it was uploaded as

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, very cool trick!

Answer (score 17):

Dropbox has modified it so that `wget` will do the right thing and retrieve the file instead of the interstitial.

Use "Share Link" to retrieve the direct link to the file.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, it's trivial with the share link.

Comment: Nice! I got a `wget: No match` output, which was solved using the link enclosed within single quotation marks (due to the `?` in the url maybe?)

Comment: You sure that is the correct answer. It seems download is only for folks with business account! Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Saw this question and thought this may help someone trying to download many files at once.

Here's a small Windows CMD/Batch script you can use.
It can easily be adjusted to work under a Bash shell (Mac/Linux/etc).
It uses [CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin). WGET should also work with some minor adjustments..

1. Install [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin) for Windows.
2. Put the individual SHARED links in a text file (1 per line).
3. Adjust all the "?dl=0" parameter(s) in your text file to "?dl=1" and save.
4. Copy script below to a file called 'geturllist.cmd' (or your choosing)
5. Open a CMD prompt and execute the CMD script.

Downloaded files will appear in current working directory you executed script from.

NOTE:
*You must have properly formatted SHARED LINKS that "Anyone with the link" can open. This script does NOT work with password protected links or shares based on a Dropbox login/email.*
NOTE:
*If the single file or file group(auto zipped) is over a certain size, it will fail with error ("The (zip) file is too large. Please add it to your Dropbox."). In this case you must do as it says.. this script will not work because share link isn't directly downloadable.*

**Example text file:**
("RandomShareCharacters/Here" will be replaced with what it says in share link)

```
 https://www.dropbox.com/sh/RandomShareCharacters/Here?dl=1
 https://www.dropbox.com/sh/RandomShareCharacters/Here?dl=1
 https://www.dropbox.com/sh/RandomShareCharacters/Here?dl=1
```

**geturllist.cmd:**

```
@echo off
set count=0
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF [%1]==[] GOTO BLANK
SET PARAMETER=%1
SET _PARAMETER=%PARAMETER:~0,2%

IF [%1]==[/?] GOTO HELP
IF [%1]==[--help] GOTO HELP
IF %_PARAMETER%==-h GOTO HELP

IF EXIST %1 (

  for /f "delims=" %%u in (%1) do (

      set /a count=count+1
      curl -kL "%%u" -O -J

      REM For other share sites:
      REM (ZIP EXAMPLE) if no filename type header sent:
      REM > curl -kL "%%u" -o "!count!.zip"
      REM > echo "!count!.zip"
      REM Will download file(s) called 1.zip, 2.zip, etc.
      )
  ) ELSE (
GOTO BLANK
)
GOTO DONE

:HELP
ECHO.
ECHO    Usage:
ECHO.
ECHO    geturllist [path]\[filename]
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO    Required Parameters:
ECHO.
ECHO    [filename]  A text file with one url per line
ECHO    -h      Help
ECHO.
GOTO DONE

:BLANK
ECHO.
ECHO Error: no input file found

:HELPMSG
ECHO.
ECHO Try -h for Help

:DONE
ECHO.
ECHO Exiting.
ECHO.
```

Example Usage:

`geturllist.cmd X:\somepath\dropbox.txt`

Comment: Down-votes with no comments are lovely. Thanks. Hurt your feelings?

Comment: Unbelievable why people downvoted this answer ffs, upvoted.

Comment: Is there a way to get all links automatically? There are hundreds of files I need to download!

Comment: @NagabhushanSN - How are they shared? You need a list of the links (put in a text file) beforehand for the above batch file to work. I was frequently emailed a bunch of dropbox links in the past and got sick of clicking each one so made the script.

Comment: The [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qthq0sume2e618n/AADc2_V_w1WZhxkhATMxq_xSa?dl=0) to the folder containing the files is shared.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN Open the shared folder. Do not click on any file. Click "Download" (upper-right of screen). Dropbox will offer a ZIP download of the shared folder with all objects inside.

Comment: I tried that. But unfortunately, the size is much larger and Dropbox doesn't download stating that error

Answer (score 0):

There is a python script on GitHub which accomplishes this:

https://github.com/dpdornseifer/dropbox_download

Also the dropbox server does not support resuming transfers.

It seems that dropbox supports the use of wget as a client and automatically redirects to the right file. Or perhaps wget is merely following redirects?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and most guaranteed method for these type of downloads is to use google chrome's developer tools.

- Press F12 to open developer tools
- Go to network tab
- Press the download link to start the download
- Find the download event in the network events
- Right click the line and select "Copy as cURL (bash)" or windows if you want
- The url will look like this:

  ```
    curl "http://yoururl.com/yourfile" -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H "Origin: http://yoururl.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Referer: http://yoururl.com/downloadpage" -H "Cookie: e07214fb60a1a; _ga=98987; "
  ```
- Replace **`curl`** with **`wget`**
- Replace **`-H "some headers"`** with **`--header="some headers"`**
- Add `-o` parameter
- The new command will look like this:

  ```
    wget "http://yoururl.com/yourfile" --header="Pragma: no-cache" --header="Origin: http://yoururl.com" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" --header="Accept: */*" --header="Cache-Control: max-age=0" --header="Referer: http://yoururl.com/downloadpage" --header="Cookie: e07214fb60a1a; _ga=98987; " -o test.txt
  ```
- Paste that to your bash window
- Press enter and enjoy your download.

Comment: OP requested usage with wget.

Comment: This is what I used. It works great. I tried it in Edge.