# Backup Dropbox files to local hard disk drive

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, shell-script, dropbox

I want to backup all the stuff from by Dropbox folder into an archive once a week. For this I have an [Banana Pi](http://www.bananapi.org) with [Bananain Linux](https://www.bananian.org). Is there a way to download all files from my Dropbox account with the command line? I think it is possible to download single files with [`wget`](https://superuser.com/questions/470664/how-to-download-dropbox-files-using-wget-command) but what about all files from an account?

Comment: There is a command-line `Dropbox` client for `Linux`: https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx. Would you like to run `dropbox` on your PC and send it to `Banana Pi` or run `dropbox` directly on `Banana Pi`? I heard that there is no `dropbox` client for `ARM`.

Comment: I would like to run it directly from the `Banana Pi` without using a PC.

Comment: I once used this: https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader. Some people say it [works on `Rpi`](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-dropbox-with-raspberry-pi) so it should also work on `Banana Pi`.

Comment: Cannot you install ssh-client, rsync on bananapi and do a  automatic rsync?  Check i.e. [Generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys). The dropobox one is a directory under the user's home in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% familiar with the [Banana Pi](http://www.bananapi.org) or [Bananain Linux](https://www.bananian.org/), but the device is ARM-based and the OS seems to be based on Debian 7/Wheezy. So that opens up the field of potential options a bit.

Looking at the details for [Rclone](http://rclone.org) look promising:

> Rclone is a command line program to sync files and directories to and
>   from
>
> - Google Drive
> - Amazon S3
> - Openstack Swift / Rackspace cloud files / Memset Memstore
> - Dropbox
> - Google Cloud Storage
> - The local filesystem

Details on how to use Rclone with Dropbox [can be found here](http://rclone.org/dropbox/).

As far as a compiled binary for Rclone itself goes, there is a [download section on the Rclone site](http://rclone.org/downloads/) that clearly shows ARM binaries, but nothing explicitly Debian. Would assume the generic Linux ARM flavor could work? It’s a simple binary so worth downloading that and trying.

But better yet, it seems like there is [a nice set of source code installation instructions](http://rclone.org/install/) provided as well:

> Rclone is a Go program and comes as a single binary file.
>
> Download the relevant binary.
>
> Or alternatively if you have Go installed use
>
> ```
> go get github.com/ncw/rclone
> ```

So if you can get Google’s [Go](https://golang.org) installed in that device—Go downloads [are here](https://golang.org/dl/)—it seems like this would be a nice option to compile from source directly on your device.

Comment: I just downloaded the [Rclone ARM binary](http://downloads.rclone.org/rclone-current-linux-arm.zip) and it works like a charm! Thanks. :)