# How to download a dropbox folder using wget?

Tags: bash, dropbox, wget

Someone shared a photo folder with me on dropbox. I would like to download the dropbox folder containing images on a Linux box, without installing any dropbox software.

I am aware of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/486351/419414) to the question, which explains how to add `dl=1` at the end of the url, but  Using the command :

```
wget 'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/my_folder_url?dl=1'
```

I get

```
ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

Since 2012 the dropbox API has probably changed? Is it possible to download a dropbox folder with wget?

Comment: Is this a public link, or do you have to authenticate to get to the shared folder? I know you asked about wget, but is curl an option? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21322615/3569534

Comment: It is a public link. `curl -L -o newName.zip https://www.dropbox.com/sh/folder_url?dl=1` downloads a file, which is not a zip file. When viewed with `less`, `newName.zip` shows a small html page with an `Error (400)` message.

Comment: You might try clicking on the link you received and see if you can download it via the web interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Oct 3, 2016, dl=1 no longer works for the Free tier users.

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

> Dropbox Basic (free) users: Beginning October 3, 2016, you can no
>   longer use shared links to render HTML content in a web browser.
>
> Dropbox Pro and Business users: Beginning September 1, 2017, you can
>   no longer render HTML content.

Comment: But I do not want to render html content in a web browser, I only want to download the file.

Comment: Yes I know, but the change disallows you from using wget curl or any other tool that utilizes http to get files