# Downloading Dropbox folders by command line?

Tags: dropbox

Is there a way to do this? All the files I need are organized by folder (of which there are many), so it would be great if I could just download all the folders. I tried `wget https://www.dropbox.com/....dl=1` but that just gave me a `500 Internal Server Error`.

EDIT: I read that Dropbox has disabled http rendering so I guess I can't use wget or curl. Is there no other way to do this? I would rather not download via browser and need to download via command line.

Comment: Is this intended for your own Drobox account or a third-party account?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to download dropbox files using wget command?](https://superuser.com/questions/470664/how-to-download-dropbox-files-using-wget-command)